# Cooper wave function and gap function have same symmetry properties

Tags: condensed-matter, angular-momentum, solid-state-physics, symmetry, superconductivity

It says the symmetry of Cooper pairing wave function $\Psi(r_1,r_2)_{s,s'}$ and mean field parameter $b(r_1,r_2)_{s,s'} = \langle GS| \psi(r_1)^\dagger_s \psi(r_2)^\dagger_{s'}| GS \rangle$ have similar symmetry properties and can be writen as
$$
\phi(R)f(r_1-r_2)\chi_{s,s'},
$$
with $R = (r_1+r_2)/2$ as center of motion.
$f(r_1-r_2)$ can be classified as angular momentum of rotaion symmetry $l = 0,1,2,...$ and $\chi_{s,s'}$ as spin singlet and triplet.
Therefore, superconducting gap function can be classified in a same way.

How can we understand, **in an exact way**, $\Psi(r_1,r_2)_{s,s'}$ and $b(r_1,r_2)_{s,s'}$ have same structure above, although it is intuitively reasonable.